# Rust protobuf serialization is all messed up

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using `rust-protobuf` version `2.4`
I have following code

```
let mut msg = vec![];
let mut str = protobuf::CodedOutputStream::vec(&mut msg);
let mut rmsg = user_manager::user::user_data::new();
rmsg.set_id("1234".into());
rmsg.set_nick("test".into());
str.write_message(1, &rmsg).unwrap();
str.flush().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", msg);
let test: register_msg = protobuf::parse_from_bytes(&msg[..]).unwrap();
println!("serialized: {:?}\noriginal: {:?}", test, rmsg);
```

and the relevant proto description is as follows

```
message user_data{
    string id           = 1; //required
    string nick         = 2;
    string theme        = 3;
    string admin_id     = 4;
    string lang         = 5;
    double credit       = 6; //required
    double bonus_credit = 7; //required
};
```

and what i get as a result is all messed up 
[image: output]

First of all, why do I need to enter a number if im serializing the entire message? that's a really weird design.

Secondly, the first field as you may see in the proto file is the id but output from serialization shows the protobuf package serialized everything into the nick field which is the second field.

Am I doing something wrong or might this be a bug in the library?

UPDATE 1:

I have changed `write_msg` to `write_to_bytes`
this is how my code looks now.

```
let mut rmsg = user_manager::user::user_data::new();
rmsg.set_id("1234".into());
rmsg.set_nick("test".into());
let msg = rmsg.write_to_bytes().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", msg);
println!("{:?}", &msg[..]);
let test: register_msg = protobuf::parse_from_bytes(&msg).unwrap();
println!("serialized: {:?}\noriginal: {:?}", test, rmsg);
```

and still, the output is all messed up.
[image: out]

Comment: Looking at `write_message`'s description, it only writes one field. Try `rmsg.write_to(&mut str)`, I'm just guessing that may work based on the docs.

Comment: Why do you think it is the Nick field instead of Id which is index one that still remains a mystery:)

Comment: @JayDepp btw write_to does not exist

Comment: Do you have the Message trait in scope? [Here's the method.](https://docs.rs/protobuf/*/protobuf/trait.Message.html#method.write_to)

Comment: I included that now but the output remains the same write_to and write_message both behave incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Message::write_to_bytes` to serialize a message that can be parsed with `parse_from_bytes`.

Also, make sure that you are deserializing the same type that you serialized.

Here's an example program that works correctly:

```rust
mod protos;
use protobuf::Message;
use protos::user_data::user_data;

fn main() {
    let mut rmsg = user_data::new();
    rmsg.set_id("1234".into());
    rmsg.set_nick("test".into());

    let msg = rmsg.write_to_bytes().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", msg);

    let test: user_data = protobuf::parse_from_bytes(&msg).unwrap();
    println!("serialized: {:?}\noriginal: {:?}", test, rmsg);
}
```

Comment: I still get the exact same result id is used as nick and id does not exist in the deserialized struct.

Comment: Your code still uses `user_data` for the serialized value and `register_msg` for the deserialized value.  Using two different types like this will not work.  Use the same type for both values.

Comment: Oh such a silly stupid mistake. How didnt i see that. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
str.write_message(1, &rmsg).unwrap();
```

writes the message `rmsg` as a submessage with field id `1`. So the fields end up one nesting level deeper, as if your `.proto` was:

```
message wrappermsg {
    user_data msg = 1;
}
```

The correct method is:

```
rmsg.write_to(&mut str);
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not change anything the result is still wrong @jpa